# Getting Corresponding Data from database onChange of Select Option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm developing a system with codeigniter framework but I just hit a snag. I've spent two days now trying to show corresponding data of a selected item populated from the database in a textbox.

### Code from View

```
<td>
 <select class="form-control" id="items_goods" name="items_goods" style=" width:150px;">
  <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Select Item</option>
  <?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
  <option value="<?php echo $item['id'];?>"><?php echo $item['item_name']; ?> </option>
   <?php endforeach;?>
    </sel<ect>
    </td><td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="<?=echo $item_goods" ></td>
```

### Code from Controller

```
public function new_sale(){
$data['title']='Add sale';
$data['id']=$this->input->post('item_goods');
$data['items']=$this->interface_model->get_item_data();
$data['item_id']=$this->input->post('items_goods');
$this->session->set_flashdata('posted_id',$data['id']);
$this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id($data['item_id']);
        $this->load->view('templates/header_interfaces');
        $this->load->view('interfaces/new_sale', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer_interfaces');}
```

### Code from Model

```
public function get_item_data_by_id($item_id){

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('stock');

 $this ->db->where('id',$item_id);
 $query = $this->db->get(); 
 return $query;}
```

### Script

```
$('#items_goods').change(function(){
var items_goods= $('#items_goods').val();
    alert('here'+' '+items_goods);
    var url = "new_sale";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {items_goods:items_goods },
        type: 'post',
        cache: "false",
      });});
```

[image]

My problem here is **onChange** of the select option. The data is passed to the controller, however any variable I set to the post variable returns null. I even tried setting it to a flashdata variable and it also returned null. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm also open to any other alternatives to get the corresponding data of the selected option to a textbox.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your data receive is wrong. Following is wrong

```
$data['id'] = $this->input->post('item_goods');
```

It will be like as follows

```
$data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
```

Because you are sending data by `id` from ajax not as `items_goods`

However your `url` in ajax also can be improved

Comment: With the url, when I use the baseurl()+controller_name/method I get a 404 error

Comment: Also I used the $data['id'] initially when the data wasn't passed. I dint edit out that part when posting the question.. but that didn't work either

Comment: `$data['id']` is not issue, problem is `$this->input->post('item_goods');`. It will be `$this->input->post('id');` ALso URL will be `site_url('controller/method')` @mcprilla79

Comment: @mcprilla79 Also I can see `return $query;` in model is wrong it will be `return $query->row_array();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the return value of - $this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id(..) - to a $data element.

**Change:**

```
$this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id($data['item_id']);
```

**To:**

```
$data['item_data'] = $this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id($data['item_id']);
```

**Updated Controller Function:**

```
public function new_sale(){
    $data['title']='Add sale';
    $data['id']=$this->input->post('item_goods');
    $data['items']=$this->interface_model->get_item_data();
    $data['item_id']=$this->input->post('items_goods');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('posted_id',$data['id']);
    $data['item_data'] = $this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id($data['item_id']);
    $this->load->view('templates/header_interfaces');
    $this->load->view('interfaces/new_sale', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer_interfaces');
}
```

You also have to return the result record from your **model**.

**Chime in at the Bottom:**

```
$row = $query->row_array();
return isset($row['id'])?$row:NULL;
```

**Updated Model Function:**

```
public function get_item_data_by_id($item_id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('stock');
    $this ->db->where('id',$item_id);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return isset($row['id'])?$row:NULL;
}
```

In your view file, you can access the new item data through variable - $item_data.

Answer (score 0):

After sometime reading threads and documentations, i was able to get the corresponding data for the selected option and displaying it in a textbox by altering the script, creating a new function in the controller to receive the post to pass it the model- where i made a few adjustments as well.

---

The following Codes below are the alterations and adjustment of the codes i posted earlier.

---

**Controller Codes**

```
public function new_sale(){
$data['title']='Add sale';
$data['id']=$this->input->post('items_goods');
$data['items']=$this->interface_model->get_item_data();
$this->load->view('templates/header_interfaces');
$this->load->view('interfaces/new_sale', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer_interfaces');}
```

....................................................................................................................................................

```
public function get_item_details(){

    $item_id=$this->input->post();
    $this->load->model('interface_model');
    $item_data=$this->interface_model->get_item_data_by_id($item_id);
    echo json_encode($item_data);

 }
```

**Model Codes**

```
public function get_item_data_by_id($item_id){
$response=array();
if($item_id['items_goods']){
$this->db->select('*');
$this ->db->where('id',$item_id['items_goods']);
$query = $this->db->get('stock'); 
$response = $query->result_array();
}
return $response;}
```

**Script Codes**

```
$('#items_goods').change(function(){
var item_name= $('#items_goods').val();
    alert('here'+' '+items_goods);
    var url = baseURL+'interfaces/get_item_details';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {'items_goods':items_goods},
        type: 'POST',
        cache: 'false',
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
    var len = response.length;
     if(len > 0){
    var qty_unit= response[0].qty_unit;
    var price_p_u= response[0].price_p_u;
     $('#qty_unit').val(qty_unit);
    $('#price_p_u').val(price_p_u);

     }else{
     $('#qty_unit').val('N/A');
    $('#price_p_u').val('N/A');
     }
    }
      });});
```

**NB:** i set the variable `var baseURL= "<?php echo base_url();?>"`  in my footer which is included in all my pages.

Thanks `@Karlo Kokkak` and `@Rejoanul Alam` for attempting to help me fix my issue